# Understanding the parameters of a notch filter

Tags: filter-design, bandpass

Adobe Audition has a very interesting notch filter that have been very useful to me. It has the following parameters
[image: Adobe Audition Notch Filter]

According to their documentation, the chosen frequency is the center frequency and the width is either a second, fourth or sixth order, depending on the "Notch Width" option selected.

I want to recreate this same type of notch filter using another tool, e.g. SoX, but I can't understand how it works. I've tried to recreate it using their own "scientific equalizer", using a Butterworth filter with various cutoffs and orders, but could not match the notch filter result.

How does this "Gain" parameter work? How can I reproduce this sort of filter with a traditional bandreject filter, like the one available in SoX?

Comment: From *"center frequency and the width is either a second, fourth or sixth order, depending on the "Notch Width" option selected"* it seems to me that the model for this is a simple low-pass filter {LPF} of order 1, 2, or 3 mapped to a band-reject filter (BRF) with a standard mapping in the s-domain and then likely the bilinear transform is used to make it a digital filter.  Even assuming all that, there are still unanswered questions that will make your result different from Audition.  The **Notch Width** parameter would be the cutoff of the LPF before mapping to a BRF. It will affect Q.

Comment: The doc can be found here https://helpx.adobe.com/audition/using/notch-filter-effect.html. Unfortunately it's a weird mix of technical info and marketing babble. It doesn't appear to be a standard notch implementation so without doing some actual measurements, I doubt you can reproduce it . Normally notch filters do NOT have a gain parameter. You can adjust width but the gain at the center frequency is 0

Comment: And what @Hilmar means by "$0$" is $-\infty$ dB.  But there is a gain parameter, so this almost sounds like a parametric EQ doing a cut of some specified dB.  I am not sure exactly, unless they want a sorta flattened stop band, why they need 4th order or 6th order.  Even with 2nd order, you can crank up the Q and have neighboring frequencies be relatively unattenuated.

Comment: @Hilmar Yes, I've noticed that peculiarity regarding the gain parameter on their so called notch filter. Would you please tell me what measurements can I do?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Yes, one of the experiments I've made was using their own parametric EQ, and although I could get really close using the same gain value and a high Q factor, like 800, for the "Narrow" width option, with their "Very Narrow" setting I could find no correlation between gain and Q factor. At some point I was using much more gain reduction and a Q factor of more than 10k and still could not match their results, i.e., the parametric EQ still affected a larger frequency window.